# Form submit with ajax passing form to php without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

can somebody please tell me why this code is not working I want to sent form data to PHP by post method but my PHP is not receiving any request
here is my signup form
signupmodal.php

```
  <form action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post" id="signupForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="forUserName">User Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User Name" aria-describedby="helpId">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="forEmail">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" aria-describedby="helpId">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" aria-describedby="helpId">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="forConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Confirm Password" aria-describedby="helpId">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SignUp" id="subbtn" onclick="myFunction()">
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            <?php echo json_encode($_POST);
            // echo $_POST['email'];
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
                echo $username;
                if ($password == $cpassword) {
                    //code
                } else
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<strong>danger</strong>
</div>';
            } ?>
        </div>

script.js


function myFunction() {
  console.log(window.location.href);
  $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'includes/signupmodal.php',
      data: $('form#signupForm').serialize(),
      success: function () {
        data = $('form#signupForm').serialize();
        console.log(data);
      },
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

I want to submit my data using ajax without loading the page so, please tell me where I am wrong

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: when i submit the form my php wont get data which I sent through ajax

Comment: Does page reload due to default form submit? If not - Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to see what is sent is what is expected, request status, response etc. You need to narrow this down to more specific part of the code that is and isn't working. You haven't provided sufficient debugging details

Comment: in dev tools status is 200 ok and all the inputs are also there I guess my PHP code have some problem but when I use normal method to put data my PHP code run perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You are only running `myFunction()` when you click the submit button and by then it's too late to add a *submit* event listener.

I suggest you add your listener when the document is ready.

Remove the `onclick="myFunction()"` from your submit button and add this to your script

```js
jQuery(function() {
  myFunction() // executes when the document has completely loaded
})

// or even just
// jQuery(myFunction)
```

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3

Comment: Interestingly it is actually not too late but has potential to add multiple listeners if submit button used more than once. https://jsfiddle.net/fv27a539/

Comment: @charlietfl very interesting. I honestly would have thought the submit event would have well and truly gone ahead before the new event listener could be added

Comment: I wasn't sure either as I almost never use button click for a form but decided to test it out of curiosity. It sort of makes sense , listener is being added before the click event completes